# Pop-up an imageView even if app is not in foreground

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to know if it is possible to show an imageView even if the app is not in foreground or is killed like ads are displayed after some time intervals even if the app is closed
If yes, how can we do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run code even if your app is not in the foreground through using services like `JobScheduler` or `WorkManager` in Android.

This is how apps such as Alarm Apps can ring at a later time even if the app isn't opened.

However, keep in mind that it is **DEFINITELY NOT OKAY** for you to run ads **OUTSIDE** of your foreground App. To schedule for ads to appear when you're app isn't running is easily considered as behavior for malware and it's an easy ticket to getting your app killed off and potentially your Developer account closed for all eternity.

But if you want to show an Image at a later time even if your app isn't running, *for legitimate purposes*, then you can do so through scheduling jobs through the services I mentioned in my first line.

**I repeat.**

**It is NOT OKAY to show ads after your app is placed in the background or after it is destroyed.**

**It is NOT OKAY to show ads at a later time if your app is not the foreground app.**